# How can I fix this error: E: Failed to fetch?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, ppa

How can I fix the following error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Answer (score 0):

404 indicates the page or resource is not available. You are probably pointing to a wrong ppa or the ppa has been removed. It is best that you remove the ppa from the sources.

Then run "sudo apt-get update".